# Websphere MQ remote queue performance tracing

Tags: performance, ibm-mq

We have IBM websphere mq set up that accepts message from outside world and transmits message to another internal queue manager. I want to trace time taken for this activity per message. Is anyone aware of any tool or MQ feature?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native WMQ statistics tell you how many messages per second go through a queue or a channel but do not correlate messages in with messages out.

The [SupportPac MA0W](http://bit.ly/SupportPacMA0W) provides an API trace that gives you very detailed information per queue, per thread, per process, etc.  It does not correlate either but does provide extremely fine grained control and tracing.

If you need something less powerful, the [MA0Z SupportPac](http://bit.ly/SupportPacMA0Z) will log messages through the channel.  If you run it on both channels you can correlate the times with a script by comparing MsgID in with CorrelID out (assuming these are honored as per WMQ programming recommendations).

There are some 3rd party apps which collect the message headers and times and log these into a DB that you can report on.  The main example of such a utility is [the program formerly known as StatWatch](http://www.bmc.com/products/product-listing/BMC-Middleware-Management---Transaction-Analytics-for-WebSphere-MQ.html).  This correlates message sin against messages out.

Finally, there are a number of Tivoli tools that collect statistics for WMQ at the queue and channel level or at the business service level.  Once configured, these also can correlate messages in with messages out.

Comment: Thanks what exactly is native WMQ statistics ? are there commands I can run?

Comment: The queue manager publishes statistics as PCF messages.  These need to be enabled and then something has to read and interpret the PCF messages.  You can read more on this at http://bit.ly/cmSfOC if you like.  Also, there is a command which reports on queue statistics but it is only available as a PCF command, not through runmqsc.  The MO71 SupportPac has the ability to query queue statistics using this PCF command.  The SupportPac page is http://bit.ly/bdSUfd if you want to download MO71.